# Blackberry Deployment Failed Error

Tags: deployment, blackberry-simulator

I am new to Blackberry Development. Now while run the application on simulator I am getting an error like,

```
Deployment Failed: Info: Obtained qconn connection
Info: Begin device to host file sync            
Info: All files already in sync                 
Info: File sync complete in 7ms
Info: Sending request: LAUNCH
Info: Action: Launch
Info: Debug native: on
Info: Launching com.shidhin.testDev_com_shidhin7fd6f305...
result::Invalid
Info: done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after deleting my target app in the simulator (without uninstalling it).
You can solve it like this:
1. Install BB10 / PlayBook App Manager as a chrome plugin. See details [here](http://crackberry.com/sideload-apps-your-blackberry-using-google-chrome).
2. Enter your simulator IP there (you can find it in the Device Manager, in momentics IDE).
3. Uninstall your app.
4. Then click run.
It should be working.